# Regex match anything backward till first occurrence of string

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing a log file like the below format to extract some info,
so I need to match TO_BE_MATCHED log with all logs before it till Tick2, but unfortunately it extends to tick 1, despite I make the (?) to be non greedy.

any suggestions here?

```
import re
if __name__ == "__main__":

    text_str ='''0000 :TRACE|####### Tick1 #######   | file1.c:604
    0001 :TRACE|log1                     | file2.c:400
    0002 :TRACE|log2                     | file3.c:611
    0003 :TRACE|####### Tick2 #######    | file1.c:604
    0004 :TRACE|log3                     | file2.c:498
    0005 :TRACE|log4                     | file3.c:676
    0006 :TRACE|TO_BE_MATCHED            | file4.c:555
    0007 :TRACE|log5                     | file5.c:676
    0008 :TRACE|####### Tick3 #######    | file1.c:604"'''

    regex = r"(Tick(\d+)(.*?)TO_BE_MATCHED)"

    match = re.findall(regex,str(text_str), re.DOTALL)

    if(match):
        print match[0][0]
```

===============================================

output:

```
Tick1 #######   | file1.c:604
0001 :TRACE|log1                     | file2.c:400
0002 :TRACE|log2                     | file3.c:611
0003 :TRACE|####### Tick2 #######    | file1.c:604
0004 :TRACE|log3                     | file2.c:498
0005 :TRACE|log4                     | file3.c:676
0006 :TRACE|TO_BE_MATCHED
```

Comment: Put `.*` before to consume and use [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for extraction: [`.*(Tick\d+.*?TO_BE_MATCHED)`](https://regex101.com/r/YAc6Gp/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will do the job, it match everything between `Tick\d` and `TO BE MATCHED` is there're no `Tick\d+` in between:

```
import re
if __name__ == "__main__":

    text_str ='''0000 :TRACE|####### Tick1 #######   | file1.c:604
    0001 :TRACE|log1                     | file2.c:400
    0002 :TRACE|log2                     | file3.c:611
    0003 :TRACE|####### Tick2 #######    | file1.c:604
    0004 :TRACE|log3                     | file2.c:498
    0005 :TRACE|log4                     | file3.c:676
    0006 :TRACE|TO_BE_MATCHED            | file4.c:555
    0007 :TRACE|log5                     | file5.c:676
    0008 :TRACE|####### Tick3 #######    | file1.c:604"'''

    regex = r"(Tick\d+((?!Tick\d+).)*TO_BE_MATCHED)"

    match = re.findall(regex,str(text_str), re.DOTALL)

    if(match):
        print match[0][0]
```

Comment: Thanks! it solved my problem, you guided me how to correctly use the negative look-ahead assertion (?!)

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = r"(Tick2(.*?)TO_BE_MATCHED)"
```

and if you're trying to match everything between `TO_BE_MATCHED` string and TickN where N is any number greater than 2; then

```
regex = "r(Tick[2-9]{1,}(.*)TO_BE_MATCHED)"
```

Comment: Have you tried it? The first works for `Tick2` or `Tick2315` but not for other values.

Comment: Actually, What I need to extract is the number (2) which resembles the tick number where the TO_BE_MATCHED string appeared.

Comment: @7kemZmani Thanks for your help, I appreciate your initiative, I'll make sure to add efficient details for further questions, However I already have accepted the first answer  that solves my problem regardless to the persons points... Thanks all, Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't work if you have for example `Tick2 Blah ... Tick3 Blah ... Tick4 ... TO_BE_MATCH`